# OAuth 2.0 signature parameters and Facebook

Tags: c++, facebook-oauth

I am having a native C++ desktop application in Facebook.

I created an application in Facebook and am now developing the code.

What are the parameters required in the [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) header?

I read that Facebook requires a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)-SHA2 signature. How do I generate this signature?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is not expecting any signature.